# Implement iOS 7 like Download Button

Tags: ios7

I need to implement iOS 7 like download button to show progress (Same as it is in iOS 7 AppStore app downloads).

Anybody has any idea what is the way to go about it?

Is there any existing control to achieve this or it is something apple specific and anybody else needs to implement using custom CAShapeLayer etc?

Comment: What have you tried? http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: I have not tried anything yet because I am trying to figure out if something like this going to be completely custom or is there any apple provided control (Same was the case with UIRefreshControl)

Comment: Might want to narrow in on that specifically in your question to get a good response. This one is liable to be closed as "too broad" or "not a question".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to make your custom implementation.

If you need it, here it is a very similar one:

[An iOS 7-inspired blue circular progress view](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/ffcircularprogressview)

Answer (score 0):

Check my library, it contains that button, and it is customizable https://github.com/PavelKatunin

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is an old question, asking for iOS 7 App Store download button, but if anyone is looking for the download button of the latest App Store (since iOS 11) I can suggest you take a look at [this library](https://github.com/amerhukic/AHDownloadButton). It provides the download button with progress and transition animation.
Here is a [demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i8nLK.gif).